# Cutting a string at specified lengths

Tags: c#, arrays, string, xna

I've got an array that holds strings, and I wanted to know how I could take a string and cut a part off at a specified pixel length and add it into the array.

For Example,

```
string[] string1 = { "Hello World" };
```

I'm using XNA so I can get the pixel length by using,

```
FontName.MeasureString(string1[0]).Length()
```

So for example, if the above code returns 100 pixels long how can I cut the string at 70 pixels long and add it back to the array to get this:

```
string1 = { "Hello Wo", "rld" } // Hello Wo(100px), rld(30px)
```

I've look at using StringBuilder but it measures strings in character length. If there are no possible ways to accomplish this, would there be a way to instead find out how many characters are in between the start of the string and the pixel point of where I want the string to cut off at, so then I would be able to use StringBuilder.

Edit:

So I tried looping through the array and then looping through each character in the array and adding it to a list, it somewhat works but I'm having trouble getting it to continue after it adds it back to the array.

```
string[] stringArray = { "Hello World" };
List<Char> charList = new List<Char>();
List<Char> charList2 = new List<Char>();
List<String> stringList = new List<String>();


        for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if ((int)consolas.MeasureString(stringArray[i]).Length() > 30)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < stringArray[i].Length; c++)
                {
                    if (consolas.MeasureString(string.Join("", charList)).Length() < 30)
                    {
                        charList.Add(stringArray[i][c]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        charList2.Add(stringArray[i][c]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stringList.Add(string.Join("", charList));
        stringList.Add(string.Join("", charList2));
        stringArray = stringList.ToArray();
        charList.Clear();
        charList2.Clear();
        stringList.Clear();
```

The above code returns me with

```
stringArray = { "He", "llo World" };
```

which is what I wanted but I want it to continue to do this

```
stringArray = { "He", "ll", "o World" };
```

and keep continuing to split the strings when they pass the 30px. I've thought about it and I can't seem to see why it isn't splitting further.

Comment: Setup a loop... Keep a string for the next section of the array, and add characters to it until measuring the string yields the pixel length you desire, and then add a copy of that string to the end of an array, and clear it to rinse and repeat.

Comment: I haven't worked with XNA. My (probably naive) way of doing it would be to do a binary search - take half the string and check the pixel length of that - if it's too long, take half of the first half and check that; if it's too short, take half of the second half and check that.

Comment: Does your first one need to be a string array?  Are you ever going to be processing e.g. 

    string[] stringArray = { "Hello World", "More Hello World" };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a mock-up of the logic, using a substitute check for the string length, rather than the pixel length. It should be fairly clear how to substitute that in the Measure function.

(A limitation of the substitution is that I haven't tested the case where x is too short but x+1 is too long. So do test that!)

I make no claims about performance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] stringArray = { "333", "Hello World", "A", "World gone mad and society has, too" };
            List<string> newStrings = new List<string> ();

            foreach (string currentString in stringArray)
            {
                bool finished = false;
                int start = 0;
                int end = 0;
                while (!finished)
                {

                    if (currentString.Length == end)
                    {
                        finished = true;
                        newStrings.Add(currentString.Substring(start, end - start));
                    }
                    else if (Measure(currentString.Substring(start, end - start)) == 0)
                    {
                        newStrings.Add(currentString.Substring(start, end - start));

                        start = end;
                    }
                    else if (Measure(currentString.Substring(start, end-start)) < 0)
                    {
                        end++;
                    }
                    else //adding one more made it too long
                    {
                        end--;
                        newStrings.Add(currentString.Substring(start, end - start));
                        start = end;
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (string s in newStrings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }



        private static int Measure(string s)
        {
            //you would check using something like 
            //int length = ((int)consolas.MeasureString(stringArray[i]).Length()); 
            //int requiredValue = 30;
            //but I have substituted just plain string.Length to show the logic

            int length = s.Length;
            int requiredValue = 3;

            if (length == requiredValue) return 0;
            if (length < requiredValue) return -1;

            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would also get in an infinite loop if your first character was more than 30 pixels.  So, uh, don't do that?  :P

Comment: Thank you for this, I will definitely check it out when I can and come back if I have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Found this on MSDN. Looks like it can be useful for you;

```
private void MeasureStringMin(PaintEventArgs e)
{

    // Set up string. 
    string measureString = "Measure String";
    Font stringFont = new Font("Arial", 16);

    // Measure string.
    SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();
    stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(measureString, stringFont);

    // Draw rectangle representing size of string.
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red, 1), 0.0F, 0.0F, stringSize.Width, stringSize.Height);

    // Draw string to screen.
    e.Graphics.DrawString(measureString, stringFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 0));
}
```

Method Page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't think that is relevant to my problem, I'm using XNA so I can already measure the string and draw the string to the screen however if I were to not use XNA it would be useful in measuring and drawing strings. The main problem I'm having is with the splitting of a string at a length and adding the cut up segments into an array.